# Why I'm getting memory allocation and not a numeric result?

Tags: python, numpy, vectorization

q1 : i'm writing this function and im cant understand why i'm getting the memory allocation
q2 : my id requires to use "==" in the "if" statements why is that? and how can I changed it to a "=" like I see in the examples

```py
import numpy as np

x = [1,2,3]
y = [2,1,2]
def scalar_function(x, y):
    """
    Returns the f(x,y) defined in the problem statement.
    """
    if x <= y:
        s = np.dot(x, y)
    else:
        s = np.divide(x, y)
    return s


print(scalar_function(x, y))

def vector_function(x, y):
    """
    Make sure vector_function can deal with vector input x,y
    """
    a = np.array(x)
    b = np.array(y)
    if a.shape[0] == b.shape[0]:
        vec_fun = np.vectorize(scalar_function(x, y))
    else:
        vec_fun = "x and y are in different dimensions"
    return vec_fun

print(vector_function(x,y))
```

output:

```py
10
<numpy.vectorize object at 0x000001F5790A9B80> ->>> why??
```

I tried different uses of "np.vectorize"
I expect the actual vector

Comment: see the docs for [numpy.vectorize](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.vectorize.html) it returns a callable, it should be ```np.vectorize(scalar_function)(x, y)```

Comment: Please format the code - select it and type `ctrl-k`.
.. [Formatting help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)... [Formatting sandbox](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/formatting-sandbox)

Comment: Your question formatting is off.  You haven't spent enough time with the `np.vectorize` docs.  But I'd rather you not even try to use it.  It's meant for a function that only takes scalars.  And even then isn't an improvement over a straight forward list comprehension.    Yes, your `scalar_function` only works if `x,y` are scalars, due to the `if` test.  But then why use `np.dot` and `np.divide` on scalars?  `np.vectorize` shouldn't used as a crutch to compensate for learning `numpy`.

Answer (score 0):

Let's simplify your function; and add a print debugging.

```
In [63]: def foo(x,y):
    ...:     print(x,y)
    ...:     return x+y
    ...:
```

Evaluated with 2 variables:

```
In [64]: x,y = 4,6; foo(x,y)
4 6
Out[64]: 10
```

Trying to use vectorize as you did:

```
In [65]: f=np.vectorize(foo(x,y))
4 6

In [66]: f
Out[66]: <numpy.vectorize at 0x26afb11ea10>

In [67]: f()
TypeError: 'int' object is not callable
```

Where did the `4 6` line come from?  from `foo(x,y)`. All you were doing was:

```
In [68]: np.vectorize(10)
Out[68]: <numpy.vectorize at 0x26afb11e7a0>
```

What you should do is give the function - unevaluated - to `vectorize`, and expect to get back a function:

```
In [69]: f=np.vectorize(foo)    
In [70]: f(x,y)
4 6
4 6
Out[70]: array(10)
```

In contrast to [64] the result is an array, and `foo` was called twice, the first time to determine the return dtype. If you don't understand that, you didn't READ THE DOCS!

Now `f` can be called with arrays (and equivalent lists):

```
In [71]: f(np.arange(3),[3,4,5])
0 3                  # again, a trial calc
0 3                  # scalar value pairs
1 4
2 5
Out[71]: array([3, 5, 7])
```

But for a function like `foo`, we don't need `vectorize`.  And the result will be much faster:

```
In [72]: foo(np.arange(3),[3,4,5])
[0 1 2] [3, 4, 5]
Out[72]: array([3, 5, 7])
```